Splitting audio input (mic) and output (speakers) between devices
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.
I purchased a NZXT mini microphone in an attempt to move away from headphones (Logitech G930) in meetings.  The NZXT microphone apparently also comes with its own audio sink, which causes PulseAudio to change the Line Out - Built-in Audio option to automatically defer to the NZXT's audio sink instead of the Realtek port (green 3.5mm motherboard jack) which goes to my desktop speakers.
With the NZXT plugged in, the Line Out system setting routes through its audio port.  Is there a simple way to separate these--i.e., select the NZXT as the input (mic) and have the output (desktop speakers) take back the routing for the Line Out - Built-in Audio system setting?
